# Emacs regexp - replacing text strings, query replace regexp

Tags: regex, emacs

It seems simple enough but I can't get it done.
My text file looks like this :

```
Johnson Cary, 2009, This important article, 109 pages.

Smith Tom, 2003, Much ado about nothing: a study, 89 pages.
```

I need this :

```
Johnson Cary%2009%This important article%109 pages.
```

Any special character unlikely to appear in text will do. The end goal is to end up with a .csv then a .xls file.

I am using

```
^\([^,]+\)\([,]\)
```

to find the first occuring comma but when I try to replace with

```
 \1 %
```

it does not work, nor any kind of close combination of that sort for that matter.

Any help will be dearly welcome!

Thank you much in advance.

Comment: That wouldn't replace *more* than one comma, but it works just fine for the first one. In what way is it not working for you? Note that this may not be a safe approach (are escaped/quoted commas permitted in the data in any format?).

Comment: A tip when working with regexps is to build them with a visual feedback: http://wikemacs.org/wiki/Regexp

Answer (score 1):

Replace this:

```
^\([^,]*\), \([^,]*\), \([^,]*\), \(.*\)$
```

with this:

```
\1%\2%\3%\4
```

to get the correct result.

Comment: Wow! The computer worked its magic! I should have asked 3 hours ago. Thank you, thank you. Love from Paris.